# Page not found error message when template exists

Tags: python, django

I keep encountering the error message:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/teachers/app-instructor-billing.html

I know this typically means that I have not set the correctly configured my urls.py to return a view for the defined path. However, from my understanding I have done this and i'm still getting this error message

Here is my urls.py

```
path('teachers/', include(([
    path('', teachers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='app-instructor-dashboard'),
    path('logout', teachers.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path('edit_user', teachers.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
    path('billing', teachers.billing_info, name='app-instructor-billing'),
    path('mentor_messages/', teachers.mentor_messages, name='mentor_messages'),
], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers')),
```

Here is my views.py(teachers.py):

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
def billing_info(request):
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-billing.html')
```

and my html:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'teachers:billing' %}">Edit Billing</a></li>
```

Comment: Your problem is that the following url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/teachers/app-instructor-billing.html, is giving a 404 correct?  I don't see why you think this is an error.  What view are you expecting that url to use and why?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I click edit billing in my html, urls.py then finds a corresponding view for teachers:billing, which is teachers.billing_info. Which then renders the html returned in my billing_info function, or am i missing something? This has worked for other urls I have

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  I see your problem now.  You are using the wrong namespace in the url tag.  It should be `teachers:app-instructor-billing` instead of `teachers:billing`

Comment: @ReinstateMonica getting this error message now
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'app-instructor-billing' not found. 'app-instructor-billing' is not a valid view function or
pattern name.

Comment: What is the name of the app this `urls.py` is in?  Or is it in your root project folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a namespace in your url configuration which is `teachers`, so when you call a url use name space followed by url name.

```
<li><a href="{% url 'teachers:app-instructor-billing' %}"> Billing List</a></li>
```

Comment: weirdly i'm starting to get this error message when I try this 'Reverse for 'app-instructor-billing' not found. 'app-instructor-billing' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
'

Comment: this is what i wrote 
<li><a href="{% url 'teachers:app-instructor-billing' %}">Billing</a></li>

Comment: returns this error
TypeError: include() got multiple values for argument 'namespace'